# Firing events in java

Tags: java, javabeans

Why method firePropertyChange (String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) in class PropertyChangeSupport don't check that old and new value can be null at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean "why doesn't `firePropertyChange(String,Object,Object)` handle the case of both objects being equal to `null` the same way it handles the case of objects being `Object#equals`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PropertyChangeEvent javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) may give some clue about it:

> Null values may be provided for the old and the new values if their
>   true values are not known.
>
> An event source may send a null object as the name to indicate that an
>   arbitrary set of if its properties have changed. In this case the old
>   and new values should also be null.

So it looks like having `oldValue==null` and `newValue==null` can have some special meaning when `source==null` as well. Because of this is may want to always propagate the change when both values are `nulls` even though they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean, but here is actual code that is definitelly more clean than me trying to explain it :)

```
/**
     * Reports a bound property update to listeners
     * that have been registered to track updates of
     * all properties or a property with the specified name.
     * <p>
     * No event is fired if old and new values are equal and non-null.
     * <p>
     * This is merely a convenience wrapper around the more general
     * {@link #firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent)} method.
     *
     * @param propertyName  the programmatic name of the property that was changed
     * @param oldValue      the old value of the property
     * @param newValue      the new value of the property
     */
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (oldValue == null || newValue == null || !oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
            firePropertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this.source, propertyName, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }
```